# Custom method from a function giving me Uncaught TypeError: 'function.method' is not a function

Tags: javascript, function, object, javascript-objects

I'm trying to make a custom method from a function. I know there are different ways but I want to know why this particular syntax doesn't work.
this is the error it's giving me

```
Uncaught TypeError: test.print is not a function
```

this is the code below

```
const test = () => {
    return{
        print: (value) => (console.log(value))
    }
}

test.print('Hello World')
```

I want to know why this doesn't work.

Comment: because `test()` returns an object with a method of `print` but you're not calling `test()` you're calling `test`, you could `test().print('hey')` or `let blah = test(); blah.print('hey')` if that makes more sense

Comment: Or `const test = { "print": (value) => console.log(value) };`. Then: `test.print(...` works.